# Refactoring tool in VS 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

At University we have VS 2005 and it has some refactoring tool like rename, extract method, extract class, etc.

I have decide to download VS 2008 from MSDN and it has only Rename and Extract method, how can I activate the other?

EDIT:  I have downloaded Microsoft VS 2008 C# Express Edition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you downloaded the Express Edition? The Express Edition does not have all Refactoring. At University you might have version other than Express.

### Update:

Since you posted that you have the Express Edition : You cannot have those refactoring tool from Visual Studio that you had at school. The Express Edition limit your functionnalities. See this chart: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2005/aa700921.aspx). Go check at your school to download an Academic version (usually offer to University). This way you can get the full version with all refactoring tool.

Comment: I have the Express and will see with the teacher if I can get the full version.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a free edition of Refactor! from [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/)

[Refactor! for VB](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/VBRefactor/)

[Refactor! for ASP.NET](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorASP/)

[Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/)

Comment: If he is on Express Edition I do not think so :P

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/VBRefactor/ This is not supported for Express. Who voted up???

Comment: I imagine it was voted up before it was confirmed that Rogez confirmed they were using the Express Edition

Answer (score 0):

If you access MSDN through the Uni MS Academy (I think that is what is was called when I was at uni) you should have access to the full version of VS 2008 Pro (along with other OS and IDEs), so I'd go for that. Over the Christmas period use Resharper 4.1 trial version and when your student loan comes in in January splash out on a full license (should be able to get an academic license). Resharper comes in very useful, I use it at work and home (in vs 2005 and 2008) :-)